# Replication of specific tables using Postgres 9.4.4 and Amazon Web Services

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, transactional-replication, postgresql-9.4

I have currently setup a **Postgres 9.4.4 RDS** instance on Amazon Web Services. On this instance I hold 20 tables. In addition I also have Postgres 9.4.4 installed on my local server (OS: 64-bit Linux) which holds about 30 tables under one database. Both the cloud instance and my local server instance have overlapping tables i.e. there are some tables on the cloud that I replicate to my local and vice versa. I am not well versed with Postgres Replication procedures as I have never needed them and at the moment have been doing the transfer rather inefficiently via python scripts to read/write/append tables between these two databases.

I would appreciate any guidance from the community on what is the best procedure. Ideally I would like a solution where some tables on the cloud can be MASTER and SLAVE locally as well as allow other other tables to be a MASTER locally and a SLAVE in the cloud. Is this possible?

Have heard that maybe Burcardo or Slony could do this? Any good documentation/sites on this area would also be helpful.

Comment: Any help from anyone? Please let me know if I am not clear.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.LogicalReplication), logical replication is possible from RDS Postgres instances, starting with version 9.4.9.  That would solve the RDS -> local direction.

The documentation doesn't make it very clear, but it seems that from version 10.4 an RDS instance can even be the receiver end (the subscriber) of logical replication:

> Beginning with PostgreSQL version 10.4, RDS supports the publication and subscription SQL Syntax for PostgreSQL 10 Logical Replication.